# opencv2 is not creating videos properly

Tags: python, opencv, video

Hello I've in the past used this code to produce videos. Now it's not working anymore this is a sample code: I've used *'MJPG' *'XVID' always with the same result. Help please. The files are extremely small (16k for a 40 frame file)

```
   import numpy as np
    import cv2
    import glob
    import sys
    import cv2.cv as cv
    file_listr = glob.glob(sys.argv[1]+'*.png')
    #~ file_listg = glob.glob(sys.argv[1]+'./*w525_norm.*')
    file_listr.sort()
    #~ file_listg.sort()
    r = cv2.imread(file_listr[0],0)
    print r.shape
    #~ print file_listr
    print file_listr[0][:-4]+'.avi'
    video = cv2.VideoWriter('testout.avi',cv.CV_FOURCC(*'MP43'),1,r.shape)

    for i in range(len(file_listr)):
        r = cv2.imread(file_listr[i])
        #~ g = cv2.imread(file_listg[i],0)
        #~ print r.dtype
        #~ g = np.zeros(r.shape).astype(r.dtype)
        #~ b = np.zeros(r.shape).astype(r.dtype)

        if sys.argv[2] == 'r':
            cv2.imshow('RGB',r)#np.dstack((b,g,r)))
            cv2.waitKey(100)
        elif sys.argv[2] == 'w':
            video.write(r)#np.dstack((b,g,r)))


    video.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is mplayer ouptut(vlc doesn't work either):

```
AVI file format detected.
[aviheader] Video stream found, -vid 0
AVI: Missing video stream!? Contact the author, it may be a bug :(
libavformat file format detected.
[lavf] stream 0: video (mpeg4), -vid 0
VIDEO:  [MP4V]  612x812  24bpp   -nan fps    0.0 kbps ( 0.0 kbyte/s)
Clip info:
 encoder: Lavf54.20.4
Load subtitles in ./
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_i965.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[vdpau] Error when calling vdp_device_create_x11: 1
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
libavcodec version 54.35.0 (external)
Unsupported AVPixelFormat 53
Selected video codec: [ffodivx] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg MPEG-4)
==========================================================================
Audio: no sound
Starting playback...
V:   0.0   0/  0 ??% ??% ??,?% 0 0 


Exiting... (End of file)
```

Comment: What platform are you on?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something has clobbered your libvdpau library, and possibly some other media-related libraries.

Have you recently changed your repos?

If so, you *should* be able to fix this by uninstalling mplayer, vlc, or other media programs you use, reverting to your previous repos, and then re-installing the media players. FWIW, mplayer has a reputation for doing this kind of thing, although it's possible to get such dependency problems with vlc & other programs as well.

If you didn't recently change your repos, I guess this sort of thing is still possible via a regular upgrade of your existing media players, or the installation of a new media program, although your package manager *should* have warned you if it had to uninstall any libraries.

I'm certainly not an expert on this topic; hopefully someone who is will see your question. But I had a similar thing happen to me a few months ago when I was testing out some unstable repos: I lost the use of vlc, and I had to uninstall it and revert my repos to get it all working again. That was a scary day!

Comment: Mplayer is not the problem. it's opencv2. Every other video file works (and it doesn't have enough size for the data that's supposed to be in there). least it seems to be the case :(.